# Reading in text file into pandas dataframe failing

Tags: python, pandas

I have the foll. input file:

```
  1988   1   1  7.88-15.57-25.00  0.00  0.81  4.02
  1988   1   2  6.50-10.37-24.87  0.00  0.49  4.30
  1988   1   3  6.48 -8.79-21.28  0.00  0.62  3.91
```

and I read it as follows:

```
df = pandas.read_csv(inp_file, header=None, sep=' ')
```

However, because of no spaces present between some columns, they are not getting read correctly. Is there a way I can specify individual column widths?

Comment: Do you have two separators, space and dash? How many columns do you have in this example?

Comment: You can use `pd.read_fwf()` for fixed-width files.

Comment: read_csv doesn't support custom column widths, but maybe you could read the file line by line, parse it and output to a cleaned file. Then pandas read_csv would work.

Comment: Your 3rd line is malformed it has a space between the dash (`-`)

Comment: thanks all, read_fwf does the trick. @EdChum, the 3rd line is not malformed, just that column width is 6

Comment: OK, wasn't sure if that was intentional or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, [`read_fwf`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html#pandas.read_fwf)  works I thought your 3rd line was malformed but it looks pukka:

```
In [9]:

t="""1988   1   1  7.88-15.57-25.00  0.00  0.81  4.02
1988   1   2  6.50-10.37-24.87  0.00  0.49  4.30
1988   1   3  6.48 -8.79-21.28  0.00  0.62  3.91"""
pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(t),header=None)
Out[9]:
      0  1  2                 3  4     5     6
0  1988  1  1  7.88-15.57-25.00  0  0.81  4.02
1  1988  1  2  6.50-10.37-24.87  0  0.49  4.30
2  1988  1  3  6.48 -8.79-21.28  0  0.62  3.91
```